# .htaccess how to redirect fake links with query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to 410 redirect with `.htaccess`.

I have several thousand fake links in the google index

they all start with

```
http://example.com/?96ncajmj​8anbvaaxomq    
http://example.com/?6amdrg-b​zzjna2ydgwj    
http://example.com/?2ecpioij​pxgsne_n1  
http://example.com/?eamppu-s​mk2p3pjyvf0yn
```

what syntax to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`

to redirect all such addresses to 410
(all starting with `?`)

`RewriteCond% {QUERY_STRING} ^?` did not work

In apache logs i see only:

```
my_IP - - [24/Jan/2019:10:45:32 +0100] "GET /?fbdffdgfdgfdgdfg HTTP/1.1" 200 48308 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
```

btw in .htaccess there is also such a rule

```
    RewriteEngone on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=410,L]
```

to lock this fake links

/index.php​?01qpwrjvmr8kjv7e8

/index.php​?01gkby5wbr-dlvqq

and it works properly

there is also a rule

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What version of Apache are you on?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you ask for:

```
RewriteEngone on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[-a-z0-9_]+$
RewriteRule ^/?$ [R=410,END]
```

That rule should work likewise in the http servers host configuration (which you should prefer) or in a dynamic configuration file. If you really need to use one of those dynamic files then take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that is is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using above rule chances are that you operate an old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint on the unsupported `[END]` flag in that case, try using the old `[L]` flag then, it will probably work the same here, though that depends a bit on your setup.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work :(
the homepage is still opening by entering these fake links

Comment: So the question _you_ need to answer is: why... Did you read what I wrote besides the actual rules? So: can you confim that the rules are applied _at all_? How? Does your http servers error log file reveal anything of interest? If nothing helps you will need to enable rewrite logging. The official documentation of the apache rewrite module explains in detail how to do that.

Comment: the problem was solved by the rule


    
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
    RewriteCond %{ENV:PAGE_URL} !yes
    RewriteRule ^ - [G]

Comment: That might redirect, but it is not exactly robust... `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .` says _anything_ that has a eruy string appended. Are you really sure that is what you want? OK, then fine, glad you solved your issue!

Comment: you were right, this rule cuts too much there is a problem with the site's operation 
Can you say something about the rule in my second answer? 
does it make your rule not work? 

# BEGIN WordPress <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /index.php [L] </IfModule> # END WordPress

Comment: I'd say the way to go forward is to find out what the actual situation is. The rules I gave above certainly work, _provided the situation you described is what you actually have_ ... I suspect that actually the requests target `/index.php` and _not_ `/` as you claimed. Various reasons why that might be. Be let's put that aside. You should try to get the requests getting matched by the rules I gave, since those are more precise and therefore robust than what you suggest.